# Yii2 Count all record in table

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to count all the records in database and post the result? 
This is my codes i don't know whats wrong the result is only 0.

```
$id = new reportDetails();
        $id->report_id;
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => reportDetails::find()
                ->where(['report_id'=> $id]),
        ]);

        echo $dataProvider->getCount();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$id` is wrong.

```
$id = new reportDetails();
$id->report_id;
```

`$id` is object `reportDetails`, not `integer`.

Try:

```
$id = 3; //or your custom number
echo reportDetails::find()->where(['report_id'=> $id])->count();
```

Comment: the result is  1. Thank you. I'll try my best to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Use all(); after Query and then try

```
$id = new reportDetails();
        $id->report_id;
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => reportDetails::find()
                ->where(['report_id'=> $id])->all(),
        ]);

        echo $dataProvider->getCount();
```

Comment: write var_dump($id); die;  jsut before $dataprovider & check whether you got value of id or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo reportDetails::find()->where(['report_id'=> $id])->count(),
```

Comment: Thank you. But again the result is zero.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.